# France Switzerland trip

Tags: france, switzerland, family

I am attending a conference in cannes France from 17 April to 20th April
By 20 April I will be free and wish to see Paris and any town in Switzerland I am accompanied by my wife and12 year old son.
My holiday ends on 24th April
What would be the best travel plan? Would it be better to travel from cannes to Paris spend 2 days in Paris and then travel to Switzerland or the other way round that is cannes to Swiss and then Paris? 
Please guide me
Would also like to be in Disney land Paris

Comment: Based on a map of Europe, I'm pretty sure you should go to Switzerland first.

Comment: You don't have a lot of time to see something Swiss, Paris, and Disneyland Paris in 5 days, especially when you factor in travel time. You could easily spend that time in just one of those places and still not see everything there is to see. In any case, one factor here is where your flights arrive and depart, as you'll want to plan your route to most efficiently use your time and avoid going back and forth.

Comment: I agree with @ZachLipton, just skip Switzerland this time. Towns in Switzerland are not that interesting anyways...

Answer (score 1):

I feel the main attraction of including Switzerland here has to be a scenic road trip over the mountains. I think the main ones are the Forclaz pass between Chamonix and Martigny (relatively low) the Great St Bernhard pass (still closed in april) and the Simplon pass, which reaches 2000m and is usually kept open in winter.

But the route Cannes-Simplon Pass-Disneyland-Paris is 1209km and takes over 13h of driving according to [Google Maps](https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/Cannes,+France/Paris+Est,+Place+du+11+Novembre+1918,+Rue+du+8+Mai+1945,+75010+Paris,+France/@49.4207924,7.4513204,5.75z/data=!4m24!4m23!1m15!1m1!1s0x12ce8180530cffff:0x40819a5fd979e20!2m2!1d7.017369!2d43.552847!3m4!1m2!1d7.9559192!2d46.3077071!3s0x478f695070a3433d:0x8056b64e396b2fa3!3m4!1m2!1d2.7860295!2d48.8670293!3s0x47e61d18050f1017:0x6a8ca2c2fa102db2!1m5!1m1!1s0x47e66e72ebc10f6f:0xae5593252035142c!2m2!1d2.3591135!2d48.876636!3e0?hl=en). Whether it is worth spending so much time in a car (I think the time is optimistic) is up to you. You'd need to rent a car in Cannes that you can drop off in Paris, and find places to sleep along the way.

On the plus side -- the route follows the Mediterranean for a long time, passing Nice and Monaco and stretches where the mountains almost reach the sea, before it turns over the flats until it goes into the high mountains for the pass. And in Switzerland, Sion, the Rhone Valley and Lake Geneva are very scenic, and you can visit Montreux or Lausanne.

But it takes quite a lot of time, and you only have a few days. Combined with a day Eurodisney, this may result in basically skipping Paris...

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would likely be :
- Cannes to Nice : 30 minutes driving
- Nice to Paris : 1h flight
- Few days in Paris
- Paris to Geneva : 50 minutes flight

From Nice to Geneva, you will also find direct flights but there are less options than the other way.

Comment: For Paris to Geneva, consider taking the train. It takes around 3 hours, but it saves you the trip to the airport, going through security, check-in/boarding time and waiting for your luggage. Depending on where exactly you want to go in Switzerland, you may also have even more direct routes that would not be available by plane.